# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. How should I solve this?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error occurred when I was trying to run 'rosdep install rviz'. Could you please help me to solve this ?

I have installed 'indigo'.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222645/e:-unable-to-correct-problems,-you-have-held-broken-packages.-how-should-i-solve-this-?/) by [Neel](https://answers.ros.org/users/25346/neel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your Ubuntu package manager (apt) has gotten into a bad state, and can't do anything until you fix it. This can happen if the package install process is interrupted or encounters an error.

You can try `apt-get install -f` to see if apt can recover; otherwise you'll need to figure out which packages are stuck or broken and debug the issue.

This isn't really related to ROS; you'll probably be able to find better help elsewhere.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it is related to this issue with Ubuntu 14.04.2 / 14.04.3: http://answers.ros.org/question/203610/ubuntu-14042-unmet-dependencies-similar-for-14043/

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2015-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1